# How can I determine if ID's are grouped similarly?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, similarity

I have applied two different clustering algorithms to my data, and I would like to express the commonality among the results of these.

The data is organized as;

- "ID" = Identifier
- "Group_1" = Results from first clustering algorithm
- "Group_2" = Results from second clustering algorithm.

*Group_1* is the output of a hierarchical clustering, which had the highest CVI at k = 5, and *Group_2* is the output of k-means clustering, which had the highest CVI at k = 10.

I would like to determine the similarity of the results.

Here is the data, which I try to find the similarity of:

```
structure(list(ID = c(400100L, 400101L, 400106L, 442306L, 443110L, 
443300L, 443301L, 443302L, 443303L, 443304L, 443307L, 443309L, 
443311L, 443312L, 443313L, 443314L, 443316L, 443317L, 443322L, 
443324L, 443328L, 443329L, 443330L, 443331L, 443332L, 443333L, 
443334L, 443339L, 443344L, 443345L, 443351L, 443365L, 443366L, 
443371L, 443378L, 443382L, 443383L, 443388L, 443390L, 443392L, 
443396L, 443398L, 443399L, 443506L, 443507L, 443511L, 443512L, 
443514L, 443521L, 443522L, 443800L, 443802L, 443816L, 443817L, 
443819L, 443820L, 443823L, 443825L, 443828L, 443829L, 443833L, 
443842L, 443855L, 443859L, 443876L, 443877L, 443879L, 444101L, 
444104L, 444202L, 444204L, 444207L, 444251L, 444305L, 444307L, 
444309L, 444312L, 444314L, 444325L, 444327L, 444328L, 444334L, 
444335L, 444339L, 444341L, 444346L, 444359L, 444501L, 444504L, 
444508L, 444509L, 444511L, 444512L, 444514L, 444517L, 444520L, 
444521L, 444547L, 444548L, 444554L, 445101L, 445106L, 445112L, 
445113L, 445115L, 445120L, 445141L, 445302L, 445303L, 445304L, 
445309L, 445312L, 445313L, 445315L, 445316L, 445318L, 445319L, 
445322L, 445327L, 445330L, 445333L, 445404L, 445405L, 445409L, 
445510L, 445522L, 445552L, 445560L, 451704L, 451705L, 452503L, 
452514L), Group_1 = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
3L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
5L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 5L), Group_2 = c(7, 7, 7, 
7, 8, 3, 3, 7, 3, 9, 6, 1, 7, 7, 10, 7, 4, 6, 7, 7, 6, 3, 3, 
10, 7, 6, 1, 7, 9, 1, 6, 7, 3, 1, 5, 3, 7, 2, 5, 6, 5, 4, 6, 
10, 1, 1, 1, 10, 1, 6, 7, 6, 6, 3, 7, 7, 6, 5, 7, 6, 9, 7, 8, 
6, 3, 7, 9, 3, 7, 6, 6, 2, 6, 3, 3, 2, 7, 1, 6, 6, 6, 3, 6, 6, 
3, 7, 7, 1, 3, 7, 3, 6, 8, 6, 3, 7, 6, 7, 7, 1, 3, 6, 7, 3, 7, 
3, 7, 3, 3, 5, 5, 2, 6, 3, 1, 6, 7, 6, 7, 5, 2, 7, 6, 5, 7, 1, 
8, 7, 3, 9, 7, 6)), row.names = c(NA, -132L), class = c("data.frame"))
```

I would like to know a percentage agreement between the two groups, however I cannot figure out how to calculate it.

Ultimately, I would like to arrive at something as:

ID's grouped together in both "Group_1" and "Group_2" divided by N

My assumption would then be that ID's grouped similarly by both algorithms are correctly labelled and I could redo the clustering with the remaining ID's.

Answer (score 0):

Standard clustering evaluation measures such as

- adjusted Rand index (ARI)
- Normalized mutual information (NMI)

*can* be used to evaluate the similarity of two clusterings. It's easy to see that they are symmetric.

Comment: Maybe, I was not clear in my description. One thing, is that I want to determine the symmetry between the groupings - and here you are right. I could use one of the above. However, this does not help me in determining the IDs, which have been clustered similarly by both the first and second method, and thus does not help me in establishing the certainty of the clusters.

Comment: If you study these measures, you'll see that clustering is predicting whether *two* objects are in the same cluster, or in different clusters. So the level you'll need to argue is on pairs of objects, not single IDs.